# What language is this? And, what does it mean?

Tags: list-of-languages, written-language

I've been trying to figure out the meaning of this image, but I couldn't find anything. Anyone knows?

[image]

Comment: Questions asking "What language is this?" is off-topic for Linguistics unless concerning the reasons for different translations.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's Chinese; the big white characters read

真情—True Love

and the ones in the little red seal:

萬事如意—May your wishes come true / may everything go as you please